# ListView jumps to top on modifying footer

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to create a simple chat layout.

I have a ListView with transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" and setStackFromBottom(true).
The ListView has a footer with an EditText and a button (It's a footer because I want it to scroll with the list).

Whenever the user types in the EditText i change the text on the button, using a TextWatcher.

The problem is that when using a physical keyboard, every letter typed scrolls the list to the top, and prevents additional letters to get into the EditText.
It works fine with soft keyboard...

I've thought it might be related to the footer being changes calling the adapter to refresh, but it doesn't seem to be that.

Is this an Android bug or am I missing something?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Another important thing I forgot to add, and is very weird, when typing any letter is scrolls to top, but when deleting characters it works ok, the same afterTextChanged gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like I've solved it,

The afterTextChanged forced a re-layout in the ListView causing it to jump to top (which should have been jump to bottom because I've set stackFromBottom).

Anyway, I've switched some views from wrap_content to other alternatives, and switched from using visibility 'gone' on hidden views to 'invisible' so that the onMeasure wouldn't have to be called after every letter and it worked.

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Please accept your answer. This helps us keep stackoverflow clean and thank you for coming back and updating the ques with your ans!!

Comment: I was going to, but it says I can only accept it tomorrow... so I guess i'll accept it then

Comment: This helped me, so thanks. For me I only had to change the width of the EditText from wrap_content to match_parent so that it didn't cause any re-layout to occur.

Answer (score 0):

See whether this helps [via this site](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/)

```
//Here is where the magic happens
02  this.getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
03   
04      //useless here, skip!
05      @Override
06      public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
07   
08      //dumdumdum
09      @Override
10      public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
11          int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
12   
13          //what is the bottom iten that is visible
14          int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;            
15   
16          //is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load more !
17          if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){
18              Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
19              thread.start();
20          }
21      }
22  });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that.
I don't need to catch the scroll event, I want to stop it from scrolling at all, it shouldn't scroll when typing...